# HTML 5: remove colour from canvas at mouse click position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a `<canvas>` with an all-back background covering another html element below it.

What i want to achieve is:
when i move the mouse over the canvas and click the button i want to get a circular area (with predefined radius, where the mouse cursor is at) of that canvas to become transparent.

Since i am new to drawing the canvas i don't really know how to do this.
So my first idea was to use `context.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height)`, fill the image with black colour and `context.putImageData(imageData)` it onto the canvas.

I thought i could get the canvas mouse coordinates and make all the pixels within that circle transparent. But i am not really sure how i determine all the pixels which belong to that circle and wether this is the most efficient method for doing this.

Any help on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look up how to change the canvas's current imageData array directly. Then clear a circle by setting each pixel to fully transparent. To do this you can iterate over the square containing the circle and use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate whether the current pixel is inside the circle.

Comment: The posted answer is the best way to do this, here's how to do it manually: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ky603ua2/ (useful if you ever need more customization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canvas context's [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing) property is what you are looking for. Setting that property influences the way new shapes being drawn interact with previous ones. Setting it to "destination-out", shapes drawn afterwards will be carved out of previously drawn shapes.

Here is an example:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//fill canvas with black
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

//carve circle out of it
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 70;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<div style="width: 500px; height: 300px; position: relative;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mollis orci vitae ex viverra, eu consequat diam pharetra. Maecenas quis odio eget eros imperdiet porttitor. Nam at condimentum arcu, eget eleifend metus. In vehicula varius justo a aliquet. Etiam ac mollis justo. Nunc dapibus massa magna, nec rhoncus arcu aliquam a. Proin condimentum sem vitae dui interdum, at congue massa blandit. Phasellus fringilla velit ultrices, suscipit risus ac, commodo justo. Pellentesque sed leo massa.

Integer non magna iaculis, aliquet odio vitae, semper felis. Aliquam ultrices cursus elementum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Aenean auctor felis purus, eu eleifend neque sodales eget. Donec eu mattis erat. Morbi libero ante, ornare eget scelerisque vel, placerat quis nulla. Maecenas congue cursus purus, at placerat libero finibus vel. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse dignissim neque sapien, et scelerisque mi efficitur vitae. Nam bibendum felis eu leo venenatis, ac semper sem sagittis. Fusce suscipit varius orci. Sed ut mi justo.

<canvas width="500" height="300" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a JSFiddle for you, using compositing and the `destination-out` option, which will treat the shapes as inverted masks.

https://jsfiddle.net/ytbfnpa9/

```
const MASK_RADIUS = 50

const myCanvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas')
const bounds = myCanvas.getBoundingClientRect()
const ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d')

function drawCircleMask(x, y, r) {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  ctx.fill()
}

ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200)

/**
* Use compositing to treat shapes as masks
*/
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'

myCanvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const x = e.clientX - bounds.left
  const y = e.clientY - bounds.top

  drawCircleMask(x, y, MASK_RADIUS)
})
```